# getSingleResult() causes rollback on NoResultException

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jakarta-ee

I'm using container-managed transactions in an application running on Wildfly 14.

The following code fails due to an unexpected transaction rollback:

```
@Transactional
public User example(...) {
    User user = findUserByName(...);
    // ...
}

private User findUserByName(String username) {
    try {
        User user = userDao.findUserByName(username); // throws NoResultException
        // ...
        return user;
    } catch (NoResultException e) {
        List<User> users = userDao.getAll(); // throws SQLException: Transaction cannot proceed: STATUS_MARKED_ROLLBACK
        // ...  
    }
}
```

Reading the JavaDoc of [NoResultException](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/persistence/NoResultException.html), the contract clearly states:

> This exception will not cause the current transaction, if one is active, to be marked for rollback.

Still the transaction is apparently rolled back, as the `getAll()` (or any other query) throws an exception with the following root cause:

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not prepare statement
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:154)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:181)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1514)
    at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:135)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.container.TypedQueryNonTxInvocationDetacher.getResultList(TypedQueryNonTxInvocationDetacher.java:58)
    at com.example.UserDao.getAll(UserDao.java:74)
    ... 64 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not prepare statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:182)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:148)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1984)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1914)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1892)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:937)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:340)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2689)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2672)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2506)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2501)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:504)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:395)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:220)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1508)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1537)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1505)
    ... 107 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: IJ031070: Transaction cannot proceed: STATUS_MARKED_ROLLBACK
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.checkTransactionActive(WrapperDataSource.java:248)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedConnection.checkTransactionActive(WrappedConnection.java:1933)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedConnection.checkStatus(WrappedConnection.java:1948)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedConnection.checkTransaction(WrappedConnection.java:1922)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedConnection.prepareStatement(WrappedConnection.java:452)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$5.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:146)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:172)
```

`userDao.findUserByName` simply does the following:

```
public User findUserByName(String username) {
    return em.createNamedQuery("User.findByName", User.class)
            .setParameter("name", username)
            .getSingleResult();
}
```

Am I missing some configuration? I even tried `@Transactional(dontRollbackOn = {NoResultException.class})` (don't know if it even makes any difference in container-managed transactions) but without success.

Comment: ok this is actually just for the sake of showing, that the method is called in a transactional context. the transaction is actually started before by a method that calls `findUserByName` :-)

Comment: @Gimby done :-)

Comment: @SebastianS If i'm not mistaken the parameter should be `noRollbackFor` instead of `dontRollbackOn`

Comment: @Zeromus not according to the [api documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/transaction/Transactional.html) . And even then, it wouldn't explain why an exception which must never trigger a rollback still triggers a rollback.

Comment: Does it work if you catch the `NoResultException` within the userDao method `findUserByName(String)`? If not, does [this](https://developer.jboss.org/message/760932#760932) answer help you?